# cucumber format pdf

Tags: pdf, cucumber

I've just started using Cucumber and formatting them as pdf's to show clients.

Is there a way to make sure a whole Scenario stays together on the one page?
Is there some sort of Orphan/Widow control in the Cucumber pdf output which I could use?

Sometimes I find I end up with a page with one line on it from the last Scenario. Not only is this a waste of paper but it can be sometimes an issue when going through Scenarios with the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there are any formatters that do what you are looking for but you can always [create your own](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/wiki/Custom-Formatters).